# Return Range Based on Color

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a UDF in excel that iterates over a given range, looks for cells of a given background color in that range, and then returns a range of cells which contain that background color. I am extremely new to VBA and I'm not sure I'm even googling right to find what I'm looking for. Here is the code I gave so far.

```
Function findRed(MyRange As Range) As Variant
Dim redRange As Range
Application.Volatile
For Each cell In MyRange
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

    End If
 Next cell

End Function
```

I had found a simple function on the web that can return the count of cells that contain the background color which works fine, but I don't know what to do within the IF statement. Find the cells that are red then do what? in order to return the range of cells that are in fact red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
Function findRed(MyRange As Range) As Range
Dim redRange As Range, cell As Range
Application.Volatile
For Each cell In MyRange
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        If redRange Is Nothing Then
            Set redRange = cell
        Else
            Set redRange = Application.Union(redRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
 Next cell
 Set findRed = redRange
End Function
```

EDIT: if you want to check the returned range address...

```
Function findRedAddress(MyRange As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    On Error Resume Next
    findRedAddress = findRed(MyRange).Address(False, False)
End Function
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. I used =findRed(A1:A99) on the workbook as a test and it returns #VALUE. Is there a way I can output it in a readable format to double check that its indicating the correct cells?

Comment: I just used the MsgBox and it shows the the range. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -2):

Depends on what you need to do with the found range? For example:
    **MsgBox cell.Address** will returns the cell's address
    **MsgBox cell.value** returns the cell's content

Comment: Well I plan to use the returned range in later calculations. Essentially another IF statement in the workbook. Something like IF redRange is A1:A10, then multiply by 10.

Comment: You can check Tim's answer for putting the ranges together